# Merge multiple rows containing different values into one row

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a database with the structure:

```
Region    | OpenServicesID | DFC
K00001    | 1400           | 4
K00002    | 1300           | 3
K00001    | 1200           | 4
K00001    | 1100           | 4
K00002    | 1000           | 4
```

I have to present the data table in the following format:

```
Region | OpenServicesID | DFC | OpenServicesID | DFC | OpenServicesID|DFC
K00001 | 1400           | 4   | 1200           | 4   | 1100          | 4
K00002 | 1300           | 3   | 1000           | 4   | Null          |Null
```

Comment: Is the number of (output) columns fixed or at least has a sensible upper limit (like e.g. 10)?

Comment: Upper limit is fixed. You can take 10 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So, I want to thank all for your answers. The code that I came up with looks like this:

```
/* This Code section is to take different prefernces (in multiple rows) and put them in one row (with multiple columns)*/
SELECT account_id, A[1] IS_ID1, B[1] IS_TYPE1, C[1] IS_TITLE1, D[1] IS_QUERY1, A[2] IS_ID2, B[2] IS_TYPE2, C[2] IS_TITLE2, D[2] IS_QUERY2,
 A[3] IS_ID3, B[3] IS_TYPE3, C[3] IS_TITLE3, D[3] IS_QUERY3, A[4] IS_ID4, B[4] IS_TYPE4, C[4] IS_TITLE4, D[4] IS_QUERY4, A[5] IS_ID5, B[5] IS_TYPE5, C[5] IS_TITLE5, D[5] IS_QUERY5  
from (
    select account_id, array_agg(id) A, array_agg(type) B, array_agg(title) C, array_agg(query) D
    from temp01
    group by 1
    order by 1) z
/* This is the end of this section*/
```